# Possible values for -a option in pvs-studio-analyzer

Tags: command-line, pvs-studio

Which values allowed for `-a` option? Documentation hasn't enough info. It says only:

> -a MODE, --analysis-mode MODE (default: 4)
>
> MODE defines the type of warnings. 4 - General Analysis.

I tried to look up on pvs site. But found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MODE defines the type of warnings:

```
1  - 64-bit errors;
2  - reserved;
4  - General Analysis (default);
8  - Micro-optimizations;
16 - Customers Specific Requests.
```

Modes can be combined by adding the values.